# Use vis.js timeline in a "dateless" way (e.g. video edit timeline)

Tags: javascript, video, timeline, vis.js

I'd like to know if it's possible to use [vis.js](http://visjs.org/timeline_examples.html)' Timeline chart to build an interface intended to put some keyframes from a `<video>` element.

I've found some other libraries closer to what I'm looking for, such as [timeline.js](https://github.com/vorg/timeline.js), or [tweentime](https://github.com/idflood/TweenTime/), but they're more tied as an animation interface, and way too overkill for my needs. I just need to put keyframes with (t,x,y) values and show them in a friendly way.

The thing is that vis.js sets the 'start' and 'end' of the timeline as `Date` objects, but what I need is something *dateless*, just from 0 to 'n' seconds. I have not much idea about how achieving this with `Date`, as this is the approach *vis.js* uses.

Any ideas about how to build this, or perhaps an alternative I haven't been able to find more close to my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Timeline of vis.js is built in a modular way, so you could create a version of the Timeline that uses an other axis than the current TimeAxis. It will require to dive into the code though.

Comment: So I guess the answer is... "no" (understanding that "no" as not implemented in vis.js) ?
Just to mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: @zedee the answer is surely not "no"... it states that you can do it if you are willing to dive into the code. I need to do the same thing because I was looking for a widget to use as a timeline editor and vis.js Timeline employs Dates OOTB. Did you ultimately find a good alternative?

Comment: @WebUser, unfortunately no. But as my timeframe was very narrow I opted to find more simplistic approaches

Answer (score 3):

You can use the timeline with the following configuration that is explicitly shared in the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/supereye/7j02Legx/9/

It will provide you an interface such as :

[image: video timeline with vis.js]

You can use the options below for this setup :

```
var start = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var end = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0);

var options = {
    width:  "500px",
    height: "100px",

    align: "box",
    groupHeightMode:'fixed',
    maxMinorChars : 2,

    zoomKey: "ctrlKey",
    horizontalScroll: true,
    verticalScroll: true,
    orientation: "top",
    moveable: true,
    zoomable : true,
    editable: true,
    min: start,
    max: end,
    start: start,
    end: end,
    zoomMax: 10000000,
    zoomMin: 1000,

    stack:false,
    multiselect: true,
    multiselectPerGroup: true,

    editable: {
        add: true,
        updateTime: true,
        updateGroup: true,
        remove: true,
        overrideItems: true
    },

    onRemove: function(item, callback) {
        callback(item);
    },

    onMove: function(item, callback) {
        callback(item);
    },
    onMoving: function(item, callback) {
        let currentItem = timeline_items.get(item.id);
        if (item.start < limit_min) item.start = limit_min;
        callback(item);
    },

    rollingMode: {
        follow: false,
        offset: 0.5
    },
};
```